# Insert data into custom table in magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom, table, data, insertlisting

I have created a custom table in database of magento 2. I want to insert some data into this custom table. I want to pass this data from controller to the custom table in magento 2.4. Please can any one guide how can i do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create models

=>Resource Model ( for connect with database)

=>Model ( get and save data)

=>Collection

You can get reference from Devdoc or

https://www.codilar.com/magento-2-models-resource-models-and-collections

https://magestore-product.gitlab.io/devdocs/internship-documentation/magento/model/

Answer (score 0):

You can insert data into database using one of the below two methods

**Method 1 :**
https://bsscommerce.com/confluence/how-to-create-insert-data-into-the-table-in-magento-2/

**Method 2 :**

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('tbl_name'); //gives table name with prefix

    $sql = "Insert Into " . $tableName . " (id, name) Values ('','XYZ')";
    $connection->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace YourNameSpace\YourModule\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    private $connection;

    public function __construct(
        ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
    )
    {
        $this->connection = $resourceConnection->getConnection();
    }

    public function saveData()
    {
        $bind = [
            'column1' => $column1,
            'column2' => $column2,
            'column3' => $column3,
            'column4' => $column14,
        ];
        $this->connection->insert('your_table_name', $bind);
    }
}
```